# How to find x in a string in Python

Tags: python, irc

I was wondering how to go about finding a string you don't know what is, in a string. I am writing an IRC bot and i need this function. I want to be able to write:

!greet Greg

and then my bot is supposed to say "Hi, Greg!". So what comes after greet is variable. And if i wrote !greet Matthew it would say "Hi, Matthew!".
Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Andesay

Comment: I guess because the question is unclear. (It wasn't me) +0

Comment: You realize that unless this stays really simple, you'll need to build a real parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if command.lower().startswith('!greet '):
    put('Hi, ' + command[7:].strip() + '!')

'!greet Greg' -> [ put()s 'Greg' ]
'!Greet  Fred ' -> [ put()s 'Fred' ]
'!hello John' -> [ nothing ]
```

Comment: What module is put a part of? It says put is not defined when i try out the code sample..

Comment: you'll have to change put to a function that sends a msg. put is just an example function.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
...
input = '!greet Greg'
m = re.match(r'!greet\s+(.*)', input)
if m:
    print 'Hi, %s!' % m.group(1)
```

Comment: People who downvote and don't bother to leave a comment explaining what is wrong is frustrating. +1 though.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine they did it because you used `re.match` and then an if construct when you could've used a more appropriate function from `re`.

Comment: Or perhaps they felt that using regular expressions was overkill for this question, when dan_waterworth's solution works perfectly well.

Comment: @Rafe and @MatrixFrog Based on the question I assumed the OP would eventually want to add other commands to their system -- ones where regular expressions would be useful and where the more general solution of using `match` would work but `sub` might not.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on adding more complexity to your bot, i would suggest using regular expressions like this:

At first you define the functions your bot may need.

```
def greet_user(name):
    print 'Hello, %s' % name
```

Then you define the pattern and a dict of commands:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'!(?P<command>\w+)\s*(?P<args>\w*)')
commands = {'greet': greet_user}
```

Now you just have to call `pattern.match()` with the user input and the appropriate function:

```
m = pattern.match(string)
commands.get(m.group('command'))(m.group('args'))
```

If a user enters an invalid command, a TypeError is thrown.

Now you can add any function just by editing the `commands`-dict.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r"!greet (?P<name>.+)", "!greet Someone")
>>> m.group("name")
'Someone'
```

Answer (score -1):

if "Greg" in greet:
  doSomething("Hi Greg")

the key is that strings take the in operator

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!But what if i had no idea which name would be put there?